# Error al mostrar un Array/objetos en Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring

Tengo que recoger los datos de un formulario , Está compuesto por preguntas y  cada una tiene subpreguntas.

Mi idea es crear crear la clase subpregunta y pasarsela a la clase pregunta y devolver un array con las preguntas a la vista, pero no me muestra nada.

Clase Subpregunta:

```
public class Subpregunta {

    private LinkedList La_subpregunta;

    public Subpregunta() {
        La_subpregunta = new LinkedList();
    }

    public void Agregar_subpregunta(String subpreguntita) {
        La_subpregunta.add(subpreguntita);
    }

    public LinkedList getLa_subpregunta() {
        return La_subpregunta;
    }
```

Clase Pregunta

```
public class Pregunta {



       private int Numero_pregunta; 
        private String Descripcion; 
        private LinkedList Subpreguntas; 

        public Pregunta(int numero, String desc, LinkedList sub){
            this.Numero_pregunta = numero;
            this.Descripcion = desc;
            this.Subpreguntas = sub;
        }
 public int getNumero_pregunta() {
        return Numero_pregunta;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return Descripcion;
    }

    public LinkedList getSubpreguntas() {
        return Subpreguntas;
    }
```

En el controlador :

```
 ModelAndView vista = new ModelAndView();
        vista.setViewName("Vistas/pruebas");

        //Recojo la opción.
        String opcion = request.getParameter("txtopciones");

        //Recojo todas las preguntas.
        String[] preguntas = request.getParameterValues("pregunta[]");

        //Miro el total de preguntas.
        int cant_preguntas = preguntas.length;

  //LinkedList para guardar las preguntas.
        LinkedList lista_preguntas = new LinkedList();


        switch (opcion) {

            case "1": 

          int numero_subpregunta=0; 

        //El objeto pregunta.
        Pregunta obj_pregunta;

        //El objeto para las subpreguntas.
        Subpregunta obj_subpregunta;

        //Recojo las subpreguntas del formulario.
        String[] subpreguntas = request.getParameterValues("subpregunta[]");


        //Recorro todas las preguntas.
        for (int i = 0; i < cant_preguntas; i++) {

           obj_subpregunta = new Subpregunta();

           //Cada pregunta tiene 4 subpreguntas, por tanto hay que agrupar.
           if(numero_subpregunta % 4 != 0){ 

               //Guardo en un array la subpregunta.
               for (int j = 0; j < numero_subpregunta; j++) {
                    obj_subpregunta.Agregar_subpregunta(subpreguntas[numero_subpregunta]);
               }

           } // Terminado este punto tengo un array con 4 subpreguntas.

              //Creo un objeto pregunta->numero de la pregunta,la descripción, y el array de las subpreguntas.
              obj_pregunta = new Pregunta(i,preguntas[i],obj_subpregunta.getLa_subpregunta());

              //Guardo en un Array las preguntas.
              lista_preguntas.add(obj_pregunta);

        }//fin for 
                break;
            case "2":
                break;
            case "3":
                break;
        } 

        vista.addObject("examen", lista_preguntas);

        return vista;
    }
```

En la vista:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <c:forEach items="${examen.Descripcion}" var="dato">
             <c:out value="${dato}"/>  <br>
         </c:forEach>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento sólo para ver si iba bien quería ver si mostraba bien " ciudades - colores".

¿ Cómo puedo solucionarlo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <c:forEach items="${examen.Descripcion}" var="dato">
    <c:out value="${dato}"/>  <br>
 </c:forEach>
```

Varias cosas:

- En EL, un atributo se accede mediante el nombre del atributo en minúsculas. P.ej. `${examen.descripcion}`. El procesador de EL ya se encargará de que esto llame a `examen.getDescripcion()`.
- `examen` es un `List`, no un `bean`. Así que no tiene un atributo `descripcion`. Lo que quieres es:

  ```
  <c:forEach items="${examen}" var="dato"> <!-- En cada iteracion poner el elemento en dato -->
     <c:out value="${dato.descripcion}"/>  <br>
  </c:forEach>
  ```

Comment: Bien saca las descripcion, pero a la hora de sacar las subpreguntas <c:out value="${dato.subpreguntas}"/>  <br> me devuelve a la vista " [] "

Comment: El `c:out` te hace el `toString()` del valor del atributo que le indicas. Le pasarás una lista de subpreguntas vacía. Revisa tu código, eso ya es otra cuestión.

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!